# Ruby - Find a file by name in a folder

Tags: ruby

The situation is that there is a folder with some files (e.g. "1", "2", "3") and I need to request information about this file. One of the options is File.exists?, but it only searches by a strictly defined file name. In turn, I need to search for the required file by query from the input field, i.e. the name of the file is a variable that the user sets. Can you please tell me the best way to search for a file in a folder in this case?

Comment: Why `File.exists?(filename)` is not ok for you?

Comment: I noted that File.exists? searches by a strict parameter (the name of the requested file), but I need it to search using a variable that the user enters

Comment: Like this? `File.exists?(a_variable_that_the_user_enters)`

Comment: Yes, that is something I have been searching for the last three hours

Comment: Your question could really use a lot more detail and as a minimum should include a complete reproducible example of your code.  In your specific example, I would suggest showing what the user input looks like, what your code section looks like, what you have tried, what the undesirable results looked like, and maybe even what the file structure looks like that you're trying to access.  This is entirely a guess since your question is incomplete. but taking a stab in the dark, I'm wondering if perhaps you don't realize that you can use a ```Symbol``` and not just a ```string``` argument.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
#!/bin/ruby

puts "What file are you looking for?"
filename = gets.chomp 

if File.exists? filename
  puts "File found! :)" 
  # do something else
else
  puts "File not found! :("
  # maybe do something else
end
```

It will take the user input and then determine if it the file exists with that name (exact match only).